# Context-free grammar and Reversal

Tags: reverse, context-free-grammar

I'm designing a context-free grammar to generate this language:

```
{ w in {a,b}* | w is of the form uvu^R, where u and v are any strings in {a,b}* }
```

I would define the first two strings as:

```
U -> aU | bU | _
V -> aV | bV | _
```

And then combine those:

```
S -> UV
```

But how do I express the reversal as context-free grammar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make use of the context-free-ness of the grammar (what you're presenting so far is just a regular grammar):

```
U-> aUa | bUb | a | b | _
```

Will match things like "ababa" and "aabaa", but not "aabba".

I'll leave it to you to alter this to your needs - but keep in mind that your specified language has the possibility of `u` being the empty string, hence it generates all strings in `{a,b}*`.

Comment: Excuse my little knowledge in this subject yet. While reading about this I came across an identical solution as the one that you posted but don't quite understand it. Would "ababa" for example be split so that u = "ab" v = "a" and u^R = "ba" with just the one line of grammar?

Comment: @Gawwad: The parse, given this grammar, for "ababa" would be: `"aUa" -> "a{bUb}a" -> "a{b{a}b}a"`.

Comment: Reading the solution you posted more carefully, I was able to work that out by my self too. I've been working with finite automata and regex the whole day, so the way these work seemed really strange at first. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Would adding "V -> aV | bV | _" and then finaly "S -> UV" be a working solution?

Comment: @Gawwad: No, not really. That would end up giving you languages looking like `uu'v`. You'll want to place the V segment *inside* the U part of the grammar.

Comment: Would I then replace the U with a V such that "aUa" would become "aVa" and "bUb" "bVb", with the same definition for V?

Comment: @Gawwad: almost - but that would only match cases where `u` was a single character. You want to leave the first two parts of that rule as-is (those are what handle the `u{something}u'` pattern), and change the stuff on the end to define what `{something}` is.

Comment: "U-> aUa | bUb | a | b | _ | V" ?

Comment: @Gawwad: Yes, that would work. You can also remove the redundant `a | b | _` part from the definition of `U`, as `V` can handle that section.

Comment: Thank you for all the time you spent on this. Got it now and can finaly go to bed!